# Do i need to remove the p3 color gamut from an image before to send it to a device?

Tags: android, image-processing, color-space, color-profile, srgb

I have a web server that store user images and I need to know how to store each image (ie: `my problem is to know if I need to store each picture with or without color space profile`).

I don't quite understand how Color Space profile work. I know that android < Oreo support only sRGB, but are android device < Oreo able to convert for exemple P3 Color Space to sRGB ? or I absolutely need to send to these devices only sRGB pictures? I know that for example Instagram or 500px store each picture in both variants: with color profile and without color profile, but this means using twice storage :(

After how to convert efficiently P3 Color Space to sRGB?

Comment: You should store the image files as you received them.

Comment: but can I send P3 color gamut image to android < Oreo ?

Comment: If it is in a file then send the file.

Comment: is so, why for exemple instagram and 500px store the file in 2 variants ?

Comment: Do they? I dont know. Well upload the variant you want.

Comment: that is an answer that help me a lot ;) and yes they do ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think that an application in your chain will not be able to display your wide gamut images correctly, it is safer to convert them to the smallest common denominator, i.e sRGB.

You can perform the conversion with many tools, e.g. Little CMS, GIMP, Photoshop will allow you to do it with the various [gamut mapping algorithms ICC supports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management#Rendering_intent):

- Absolute colorimetric
- Relative colorimetric
- Perceptual
- Saturation

Or you can just perform a naive straight conversion from DCI-P3 to sRGB by computing the transformation matrix and clipping out-of-gamut values, i.e. negative values. You can [use this tool to compute the matrix](http://colour-science.org/cgi-bin/rgb_colourspace_models_transformation_matrices.cgi), e.g. DCI-P3 to sRGB using CAT02 chromatic adaptation transform:

```
 1.1474451 -0.1450487 -0.0025531
-0.0419136  1.0420663 -0.0000536
-0.0174968 -0.0696506  1.0872218
```

Comment: thanks kel Solaar ... but why the application (ie: android) can not convert herself the wide gamut image ? in this way i store the image in wide gamut and them i can gave it to ios device who support it and to android device that will convert it

Comment: Well it is entirely dependent on the ICC support level in the application chain, if ICC is supported, it will perform the conversions accordingly, if not, then it usually means sRGB is assumed to be the working colourspace.

Comment: hmm, so does android device support icc to do the conversion ?

Comment: Given what I read here: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/color-mgmt#determining-device-support I don't think the support is great in Oreo so I think it is safer to assume that lower versions are simply unable to do anything. I would convert everything to sRGB and come back to my images when Oreo adoption is larger.

Comment: thanks kel, do you think i can convert to sRGB using imageMagick ?

Comment: do you know if jpg can have wide gamut profile ? i can't find any exemple of jpg image with wide gamut P3 profile embded ! also i found this image: https://webkit.org/blog-files/color-gamut/Webkit-logo-P3.png (it's not a jpeg) but it's strange when i open it in webbrowser it is totally red, but when i open it with for example with acdsee i can see the logo on the red ... i don't understand, why acdsee can show the good color but not google chrome or even photoshop (it's also fully red in photoshop) ?

Comment: I never used ImageMagick to perform colourspace conversions so I cannot comment. Nothing forbids you to store wide gamut data in a Jpeg file thus you can generate Jpeg files with WCG profiles. The image you linked will be totally red on an sRGB display IF the ICC chain works because it embed a P3 profile: the logo colour is close to max red sRGB (221) once converted to P3 and all the surrounding colours are max red P3, thus out of gamut and clipped once displayed on an sRGB screen. Given you can see the logo, it means that ACDSee is not properly colour managed and assumes the content is sRGB.